# Time Interval Partitioning in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, partitioning

I have a table with time stamp (UTC) and for several reasons, like purging from this table (done at later point of ETL), I am trying to find out the feasibility of partitioning the table by 5 minutes or so. I have records pumped into this table in a real time scenario and my ETL process will be running in parallel.

Below is the schema of my table which I am interested in and my SQL Server version is 2016. Kindly suggest if partitioning can be an optimal way to deal with this scenario.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[F_DATA_EVENTS]
(
    [RECID] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [XMLRECORD] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [EVENT_TIMESTAMP] [numeric](38, 6) NULL
)

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[F_DATA_EVENTS] ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_EVENT_TIMESTAMP]  
DEFAULT (CONVERT([numeric](30,6),concat(datediff(second,'19700101 00:00:00:000',getdate()),'.',datepart(millisecond,getdate())))) FOR [EVENT_TIMESTAMP]
```

Comment: I'm a bit unclear what the actual problem you're trying to solve is here - are you worried about performance? Have you actually seen the issue occur?

Comment: Yes we are worried on performance . The scenario si like this Online transactions store in this table (count of table : in millions),ETL keeps processing and pushes them into other staging tables.Once its pushed successfully there is a purge process which deletes the record from the actual source table(F_DATA_EVENTS). So trying to find the possibility of PARTITIONING in 15 minutes time interval, so that the purge scans only that partition and delete instead of full scan

Comment: How long is the DELETE taking at the moment? How often are records put into F_DATA_EVENTS?

Comment: Delete is taking lesser time only but we are thinking of to apply interval partitioning(as followed in oracle environments). Also this is banking domain and you can expect more records are pumped in during weekdays and relatively lesser during weekend. There is also an initial load process which generates millions of records into that table. I hope i have answered all your doubts

Comment: PARTITION will not automatically fix your performance problems - it will actually slow things down if you get it wrong. If you are not facing any issues with the DELETE I'd suggest you run a load test with dummy data to see when you WILL have issues - if it's more than a year or two away, deal with the issue accordingly. You currently seem to be reacting to a potential problem, rather than an actual problem.

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at http://kejser.org/table-pattern-rotating-log-ring-buffer/ for ideas.  You could implement it but use 15 minute intervals (instead of days as in the article) for your computed column.  Then have another process run every X and trim off any partitions older than you want to keep.